# Object handles and array of arrays

Tags: java, blackberry

In the blackberry documentation, they say that an array takes one object handle:

```
int[] array; // 1 object handle
```

How many handles does an array of arrays take?

```
int[][] array = new int[4][2]; // how many handles?
```

I can't figure out if it would be a single one since, after all, the array can be construed as a single piece of memory or is it multiples (5 in this case) because there would be one per element in the first-level array?

Comment: What do you mean by "handles"?

Comment: As defined by RIM for their platform: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5716/BP_Data_structure_selection_447117_11.jsp

Comment: They have some weird corner case with Java (e.g. older String) but are pretty much similar in most cases. Your answer explaining that Java doesn't have a concept of multidimentional arrays pretty much means that an object handle (per RIM) would be required for each nested level.

Comment: `int[][] array = new int[4][2];` there are 5 reference variables total in standard Java, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't have multidimensional arrays, as you've found out. It has array of arrays.

Given this declaration:

```
int[][] array = new int[4][2];
```

There are 4 `int[]` arrays, each having `2 int` elements.

```
Object o1 = array[0];
Object o2 = array[1];
Object o3 = array[2];
Object o4 = array[3];
```

Consequently, this means that `array` is also an `Object[]`.

```
Object[] oX = array;
```

Just because you have an `int[][]`, doesn't mean that each `int[]` is distinct, of course.

```
int[][] weird = new int[4][];
weird[0] = weird[1] = weird[2] = weird[3] = new int[5];
```

Now there is only one `int[]`, and each `weird[i]` shares this reference.

```
weird[0][2] = 5;
System.out.println(weird[3][2]); // prints "5"
```

Comment: Sure, it's not five arrays (handles), namely array, array[0], array[1], array[2] and array[3]?

Comment: @Andreas: Five arrays objects, yes. 4 `int[]`, one `Object[]`.